# defining legends and colours for single colour box plot / points in ggplot2 (r)

Tags: r, ggplot2

A snapshot of my correct plot, and question on its behavior.

[image: A snapshot of my correct plot, and question on its behaviour.]

The problem I am having is as follows: I have two datasets (trivially, in this case, I am using the pokemon dataset in highcharter as a source, and generating a second dataset from it).

I want to draw some averages in a box plot by type (but in a single colour), and then add a second series of points in the same categories on top, again in a single colour. Drawing the chart is easy but displaying the legend has proven to be anything but.

Below is my final solution for this issue, which gives me the plot behaviour I was after. What I would like to know is why I cannot use scale_color_manual to do the same to my points (i.e. change the colour of my points, and override the title of my legend) as I do to my boxes with scale_fill_manual? If I remove `colour="orange"` from the line that creates the points, they revert to the default black even if I include the second piece of code which I believe should change them to yellow. Does scale_color_manual not refer to my points in this case, and if so, why?

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

myData <- pokemon
myData <- myData %>% mutate(type_1 = factor(type_1))

myList2 <- myData %>% 
  group_by(type_1) %>%
  summarise(
    meanHeight = mean(height),
    meanWeight = mean(weight),
    meanAttack = mean(attack)
  )

ggplot(data = pokemon, aes(x=factor(type_1), y=defense)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill="")) +
  geom_point(data=myList2, aes(x=type_1, y=meanAttack, shape=""), colour = 
"orange") +
  coord_flip() +
     theme(panel.background = element_blank()) +
     labs(x = "Pokemon Main Type", y = "Defense value", title = "My pokemon 
plot", subtitle = "with a subtitle",
          fill = "Type", shape = "Mean Attack",
          caption = "data (c) the highcharter package") +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape=""))) +
  scale_fill_manual('Pokemon types',
                    values = 'lightblue',  
                    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(alpha = 1)))
```

The code which does nothing is:

```
 + scale_color_manual('mylegend', ## this does nothing
                     values = c('yellow'),
                     guide = guide_legend(title="this", override.aes = 
list(alpha = 1)))
```

Thank you for any insights.

Comment: Hard to help without a reproducible example, but it looks like you aren't using the `scale_xx_manual` functions correctly. These will only affect attributes that are defined in `aes()`. Try `geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(type_1)))`, then supply a vector of colors in `scale_fill_manual()`.

Comment: Thanks. The pokemon data is included in highcharter so the example should be reproducable by downloading the relevant packages. I'm not sure you are getting the question - I am trying to change the colour of my points, using scale_color_manual (I'm happy with the way my fill colour is working), but it's not changing anything.

Comment: I have edited the question to include a picture of the plot, and some annotation as to what my question alludes to.

Comment: You are setting "color" in `geom_point` to "orange". `scale_color_manual()` will only affect point color if you do something like, `geom_point(aes(color = as_factor(type_1)))`. This is how ggplot knows to connect the aesthetic and the scale.

Comment: Hi @jdobres, I have tried this, but it requires me to set the colour for each type in order to get all my points to be yellow: `scale_color_manual('mylegend',
                     values = c('yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow',
                                'yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow',
                                'yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow','yellow'),
                     guide = guide_legend(title="this", override.aes = 
                                            list(alpha = 1)))`. The new plot has three legends!

Comment: Try `geom_point(aes(color = 'Type'))`, and then `scale_color_manual(values = 'yellow')`

Comment: `Error: Insufficient values in manual scale. 18 needed but only 1 provided.` This is why I ended up with the above...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary problem here is the connection between `aes()` and the `scale_xx` commands. When you pass a column of your data frame to an aesthetic, for example `aes(fill = type_1)`, ggplot examines all the values of that column to determine how fill should be represented. In this case, "type_1" is categorical, so ggplot would apply its default categorical hue scale, with its default coloring. To change those colors, you would use `scale_fill_manual` and specify a list of colors.

Conversely, if you just want to set a segment of your data to one color, you would specify that outside of `aes()`, as in, `geom_point(color = 'orange')`. No need to include a scale function. But since you *also* want a label to appear in your legend, we need to trick ggplot a little:

```
ggplot(data= pokemon, aes(x = factor(type_1), y = defense)) +
  geom_boxplot(fill = 'lightblue') +
  geom_point(data = myList2, aes(x = type_1, y = meanAttack, color = 'Mean Attack')) +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_color_manual(values = 'orange') +
  labs(color = NULL, x = 'Pokemon Main Type') +
  theme_bw()
```

Here we pass ggplot an "aesthetic" with one value: "Mean Attack". Since color is now linked to an aesthetic, you can affect it in `scale_color_manual`, and it shows up in the legend, labeled appropriately.[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much. I knew I was trying to trick the package, but clearly didn't quite know how to go about it. I hope you enjoyed the pokemon dataset, it is of course a proxy for the data that I will be using for the actual project (and it helps get the children interested in stats).